# How to bit_shift a data stream in?

Tags: verilog, fpga, bit-shift

I know you can shift by using >> or >>>, but how do I shift in the values from another data stream?

something like:

```
always @(posegde(clk)) begin
    data_shift <= data_shift << DIN (one bit?)
end
```

Is there a shortcut?

EDIT: I'm silly. I'll just concatenate the part of the signal I need.

Answer (score 0):

assuming DIN is a single bit:

```
always @(posegde(clk)) begin
    data_shift <= {data_shift($high(data_shift):$low(data_shift)+1), DIN}
end
```